# Migrate Asp.Net Identity users credentials into custom table

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am planning to implement Identity Server 3 for my application. I want to create my own tables to store users and credentials for the same. 
Can I migrate the existing user credentials to my new tables and how do i validate the credentials?